# Removing everything before exact string with regex

Tags: python, python-re

I have this string, and I'm trying to remove everything that is before `P<RU`, but nothing happens and I receive the same string. Basically nothing happens.

```
a = ("PECIMEN\n"
        "DWADWA\n"
        "P<RUSDATA<DATA<<<<\n"
        "00000000<ORUS7803118F213242803111025<<<64")
removed_text = re.sub(r'^.*?\nP<RU', '\nP<RU', a)
```

or

```
removed_text = re.sub(r'^.*?P<RU', 'P<RU', a)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the `re.DOTALL` flag, otherwise `.` doesn't match newlines, so it will only perform the replacement in the first line of the string.

```
removed_text = re.sub(r'^.*?P<RU', 'P<RU', a, flags = re.DOTALL)
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't necessarily need a regex. Assuming 'P<RU' appears once - why not do:

```
    x = 'P<RU' + a.split('P<RU')[1]
```